# How to parse Nested Json messages from Kafka topic to hive

Tags: json, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm pretty new to spark streaming and scala. I have a Json data and some other random log data coming in from a kafka topic.I was able to filter out just the json data like this

```
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet).map(_._2).filter (x => x.matches("^[{].*" ))
```

My json data looks like this.

```
{"time":"125573","randomcol":"abchdre","address":{"city":"somecity","zip":"123456"}}
```

Im trying to parse the json data and put it into hive table.
can someone please point me in the correct direction.
Thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Im trying to parse the json data and put in into a hive table.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

1. create an external hive table with required columns and pointing to this data location.
2. When you create the table , you could use the default JSON serde and then use get_json_object hive function and load this raw data into a final table. Refer [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-get_json_object) for the function details

OR

You could try the avro serde and mention the avro schema as per your json message to create the hive table. Refer [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-using-json-in-hive/) for avro serde example
.

Hope it helps